# backing out of a module update after uploading it and before the database update (new update is incompatible with my version of PHP)

Tags: 7, database, updating

I got a situation here and I don't know what to do. Drupal 7.

There's an update for reCAPTCHA so I click the button and checkboxes and whatever to update it, it uploads the files to the server and unpacks them and stuff, and then I click the "update database" link. BTW, there's two other modules being updates: rules and GA.

On the resulting page, /update.php, it first check the requirements (I rarely see this screen, it usually breezes right past it) and there's a big red error message saying that "reCAPTCHA requires at least PHP 5.5.*" and I have PHP 5.4.45.

Should I delete the reCAPTCHA module from /sites/all/modules/, and then put the files for the old version in there? If I do that, will the database updates script be confused?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I delete the reCAPTCHA module from /sites/all/modules/, and then put the files for the old version in there?

Yes, that's exactly what you should do.

> If I do that, will the database updates script be confused?

They shouldn't be - when you start an update, the current versions of modules are queried from fresh again. So as long as the current version of the module in the database matches the version in the file system (which it will if you restore to before the file system change), you should be fine.

Comment: it worked, I checked this as the answer

Comment: While this answers the title of the question, the correct solution is to update php to 5.6 and proceed with DB and module update. There is no reason for OP to be using php 5.4 which is no longer supported.

Comment: Even 5.6 has reached EOL, so technically and ideally he should be updating atleast to php 7.1, but this may require some patch work as some contrib modules are behind the 8 ball.

Comment: @NoSssweat yes, you're right